# Comparison of three functions

Tags: calculus, functions

How to prove that

$$x-x^2<\ln(1+x)<x-\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)}$$

for all $x>0$?

Comment: **Hint**: use Taylor expansion for ln(1+x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These can be proven simply with calculus. Consider the first inequality:
$$x - x^2 < \log(1 + x) \iff \log(1 + x) - x + x^2 > 0$$
Let $f(x) = \log(1 + x) - x + x^2$. Then $f(0) = 0$, and
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x} - 1 + 2x = \frac{1 - (1+x) + 2x(1+x)}{1+x} = \frac{x(2 + x)}{1+x} > 0.$$
By Rolle's theorem, there cannot be an $x > 0$ such that $f(x) = 0$, that is, the inequality holds.

Consider the second inequality:
$$\log(1+x) < x - \frac{x^2}{2(1+x)} \iff 2(1 + x)x - x^2 - 2(1 + x)\log(1+x) > 0.$$
Similarly, let $g(x) = 2(1 + x)x - x^2 - 2(1 + x)\log(1+x)$. Then $g(0) = 0$, and
$$g'(x) = 2x - 2\log(1+x).$$
Note that $g'(0) = 0$, and
$$g''(x) = 2 - \frac{2}{1+x} = \frac{2x}{1+x} > 0$$
Again, By Rolle's Theorem, $g'(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$, so $g(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$.

Sorry about the mistakes. Feel free to point out any I've left/newly created. Maybe the method isn't so solid and reliable. :-(

Comment: I like the solidity and reliability :-)!!Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's do the first inequality.

For $x>0$ we easily see that
$$-2<-\frac 1{(1+x)^2}$$

Take the definite integral from $0$ to $x$ and we get

$$-2x<\frac 1{1+x}-1$$
$$1-2x<\frac 1{1+x}$$

Take the definite integral again from $0$ to $x$ and we get

$$x-x^2<\ln(1+x)$$

Answer (score 0):

With MVT, or studying the monotonicity of $g-f$, it is easy to show this:

> If $f,g:[0,\infty]\to\Bbb R$ are differentiable functions with $f(0)=g(0)$, and $f'(x)<g'(x)$ for $x>0$ then $f(x)<g(x)$ for $x>0$.

For $x=0$ the three functions of your question vanish.

Their derivatives are:
$$1-2x=1-\frac{4x(1+x)^2}{2(1+x)^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-\frac{2x(1+x)}{2(1+x)^2}$$
$$1-\frac{2x^2+4x}{4(1+x)^2}=1-\frac{x(x+2)}{2(1+x)^2}$$

So it suffices to show that
$$x(x+2)<2x(x+1)<4x(1+x)^2$$
for $x>0$ (and this should be easy).